# If position an element fixed relative to parent is not working IE?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

If position an element fixed relative to parent is not working Internet Explorer?
[image]
I find that when I position an element fixed, it doesn't matter if the parent is positioned relative or not. It will position fixed, relative to the window in Internet Explorer.

**The Code:**

```css
// Content DIV
.row {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}
// Call Action DIv
.CallActionR {
  position: relative;
}
.CallActionA {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.CallActionContainer {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transform: translateZ(0px);
  transition: all 2s linear;
  right: 0;
}
.CallActionDisplay {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 58px;
  border: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(59, 110, 142, 0.74902);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
  text-decoration: none;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 18px 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="CallActionR">
    <div class="CallActionA">
      <div class="CallActionContainer">
        <div class="CallAction">Call TO Action</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Position fixed aligned properly on other browsers like Google Chrome and Firefox. But coming to IE 11 is not working properly. The position fixed `<div>` not aligned based on the relative window.

Comment: position:fixed only minds the wiewport. https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Fixed_positioning

Comment: *"I find that when I position an element fixed, it doesn't matter if the parent is positioned relative or not. It will position fixed, relative to the window "* - That's the expected behaviour. I doubt if any browser would so something different.

Comment: @Paulie_D : In IE rendering different from others i did not find any issues from my code. if you find anything pls do needful

Answer (score 1):

I have just ran into the same problem. Where actually most browsers (Firefox / Chrome) except for IE were doing what I wanted, but that turned out to be the WRONG behaviour. But because of using 'transform' it will 'break' the position:fixed in IE (not in other browsers). This is causing different behaviour between IE and the other browsers.

My explanation might be not very clear, so read more on http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/position/ (last paragraph at Trivia & Notes).